# is there any way to change the default type for xsd:element?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

1. If i declare an xsd element without explicitly specifying a type: `<xsd:element name="e">` what would be the assumed type?
2. Is there any way to change the "default type" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It is the ur-type, http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ur-type-itself, or `anyType`. So anything goes!
2. Not that I'm aware of

Comment: No idea (unconstrained root?), I guess some of the authors of that spec could answer. However, it's funny that it fits my mother tongue, swedish, very well: urtyp, meaning prototype or archetype

Comment: BTW: Same is true for the german language, 'ur' as exactly the same meaning.