# Axis2 fails when an XSD element has no type defined (type ur-type), but sub-types are returned in the SOAP response?

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl, apache-axis

I am facing an issue with a SOAP Web Service Client using Axis2; the XSD file extending the WSDL holds the following definition for an element in the response, notice how **no type** is defined:

```
<xs:element name="error" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Following is the actual response returned by the SOAP service:

```
<error>
   <details>Unexpected Error Occurred</details>
</error>
```

This is causing the following exception to be thrown by Axis2:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT
                at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
                at fr.cel.service.HooStub.fromOM(HooStub.java:847
```

The Service people are saying that since the 'error' element has no type define, then it can include everything such as string, date or an additional structure.

I wasn't really convinced; so, **what does it mean to have no type defined for the element** ?

Also, is there any change we can apply to the WSDL or to the Axi2 wsdl2java stub generation command, so that we avoid this ? Knowing that instead of `<details>` we may actually receive some other sub-type in the response.

Update: I'm using Axis2 1.5.4, and it appears that W3C XSD specs say that we can have sub-types in this case (when using ur-type, i.e. no type defined), so why is Axis2 refusing this ?

Comment: *Service people* are right, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104455/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-type-for-xsdelement : any content should be allowed within the `<error>` element. See also [XML Schema spec 3.3 Element declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cElement_Declarations)

Comment: I agree now.. So can I remedy this in Axis2 ? Only option until now is to manually edit generated stub code.. yuck ! There's a pretty high cost if I have to move my project to Apache CXF.

Answer (score 0):

Your service people are correct.

Per the W3C XSD Recommendation, [3.3.2 XML Representation of Element Declaration Schema Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element):

> {type definition} The type definition corresponding to the
>    or  element information item in the
>   [children], if either is present, otherwise the type definition
>   ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of the type [attribute], otherwise
>   the {type definition} of the element declaration ·resolved· to by the
>   ·actual value· of the substitutionGroup [attribute], if present,
>   otherwise the ·[ur-type definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ur-type-itself)·.

Following the link for [ur-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ur-type-itself) will yield that no type specified defaults to anyType.

You can certainly tighten the definition for `error` by providing a type that requires a `detail` element.  Whether this avoids your exception is unclear as given only the constraints of the XSD, you should be able to put a `details` element within `error`.  Your application software (Axis2) may be imposing additional requirements not specified purely by the XSD.

Comment: Checking the 'ur-Type' (empty type) definiton, the service people seem to be correct. However, as usual, Axis2 has weird behavior and is failing. Too bad I cannot define the 'details' element explicitly in the XSD since the service might return no element at all, or even another element name.